# Want to reload my page using location.reload(); after window.open() completes its execution

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to reload my web page after window.open('test.com') complete its processing. i have tried following code

```
try {
        window.open(scriptURL); //scriptURl is my which i want to open in new window.
        setTimeout(function () {
            location.reload(); //It's you code
        }, 4000);

    } catch (e) {
        nlapiLogExecution('error', 'Error requesting SLE', e.getCode() + ' - ' + e.getDetails());
        alert('error: ' + e.message);
        return;
    }
```

The location.reload() is dependent on window.open() once window.open() complete its processing then i want to reload my page.The above code is working fine. But  the issue is that if window.open() take more than 4 sec its not work fine. setTimeout is not feasible solution because we are using hardcoded time. So can anyone help me out and come with best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `onload` function on your new opened window :

```
 var openWindow = window.open(scriptURL); //scriptURl is my which i want to 
 openWindow.onload = function(){
    location.reload(); //or perhaps openWindow.location.reload(); need to check
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the window finish loading in a couple of ways.

JS

```
object.addEventListener("load", myScript);
```

jQuery

```
$(window).on('load', function () {

 });
```